# Passing stripe idempotency key to payment intent in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

I am trying to pass the Stripe idempotency key to a Stripe payment intent in Laravel. The actual payments gets processed fine but I don't see the Idempotency key appear in the request (in the Stripe logs). Any guidance is really appreciated:

Code snippet below

```
$intent = $this->createPaymentIntent([
    'amount' => $stripe_amount,
    'currency' => config('services.stripe.currency'),
    'payment_method' => $paymentMethod,
    'transfer_data' => $transferDataArray,
    "metadata" => $metaDataArray,
],  [
    'idempotency_key' => '**********'
]);
```

Comment: Not sure how private that key is supposed to be, but generally, you shouldn't post credentials :)

Comment: It was just a temporary random key, but thanks for obfuscating

Answer (score 1):

The idempotency key, if used, should appear in the upper section of your request log panel (green box):
[image]

The "original request" (blue box) points you to the initial request if the one you're looking at was a replay.

Comment: Even though I am passing the key, it doesn't appear. I must be passing it in the wrong way